# try catch in function in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Does the below function fine with reference of Async Node.JS? 
I mean is it written correctly, the error will be  handled or it is written wrong in terms of Async Node.JS?
If it is written wrong how to write it correctly in Async Node?

```
function genid(callback){
  try {
    var id = mylib.generate();
    callback(null, id);
  } catch(err){
    callback(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for starters, if `mylib.generate()` returns id synchronously, I doubt that there is need for async, it can simply be:

```
function genid(callback){
    return mylib.generate();
}
```

but if `mylib.generate()` is async, how are we going to get the error sync unless `mylib` or `mylib.generate` does not exist or incorrectly defined... assuming it is async:

```
function genid(callback){
    try{
        mylib.generate(function(err, id){       // assuming that is how mylib.generate callback is styled
                if(err) return callback(err);
                callback(null, id);
        });
    }catch(e){
        callback(e);
    }
}
```

or it can simply be reduced to:

```
function genid(callback){
    try{
        mylib.generate(callback);
    }catch(e){
        callback(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So that won't catch all the errors out there. A simple way to test this is to write some code that looks like yours.

```
function main() {
  try {
    cb();
    console.log('This will still run because async.');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('This will not run.');
    console.log(e);
  }
}

function cb() {
  setInterval(function() {
    throw 'This is an error!';
  }, 1000);
}

main();
```

That code will break and not be handled by try/catch. So what does that code catch?

```
function cb() {
  throw 'This is an error';
  setInterval(function() {
    throw 'This is an error! But it will not run this time.';
  }, 1000);
}
```

In this code, we changed cb to immediately throw an error. It will also catch errors that called synchronously.

```
function cb() {
  (function() {
    throw 'This will also throw.';
  })();
}
```

So now that you've learned some JavaScript stuff, what can we do? There isn't a JavaScript language construct to force you to catch all async errors. Node has some stuff to help you catch errors - you can read about it [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html). Here's an example:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
});

throw 'An error';
```

This will catch the error thrown. (Be sure you handle the error before you throw one.)

There is a pattern known as [Promises](https://www.promisejs.org/) that are popular in async JavaScript. You can't force things to catch correctly, but if you use libraries which implement Promises correctly, you can use this pattern.

```
var Promise = require('promise');

function catchThis() {
  return Promise.reject(new Error('This is an error'));
}

var p = Promise.resolve(catchThis());

p.then(
  //on Success
  function() {
    console.log('This will never call');
  },
  // on Error
  function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
);
```

Note, I'm not "throwing" anything here. It didn't solve my catching all random "throws" problem, but it gives me a model to manage errors without risking an error slipping through. Note: ES6 (the latest JavaScript Standard) supports Promises natively.